# Problem resolving mongodb/monk find() promise

Tags: node.js, express, monk

I've run into a problem that simple mongodb/monk find() doesn't work. I know find() returns promise and all 3 ways to resolve it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

This is my code. All of 3 routes doesn't return at all and need to be canceled:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    const db = require('monk')('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/storage');
    const files = db.get('fs.files');

    router.get('/1', async (req, res) => {
      const result = await files.find();
      res.json(result);
    });

    router.get('/2', (req, res) => {
      files.find()
       .then(
          (result) => { res.json(result) },
          (error) => { res.json(error) }
       );
    });


    router.get('/3', (req, res) => {
      files.find({}, (result) => {
        res.json(result)
      });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

UPDATE:
I've got rid of munk and native MongoDB driver does the job:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  mongo.MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, mongoClientOptions, async (err, conn) => {
    assert.ifError(err);
    const files = await conn.db('storage')
      .collection('fs.files')
      .find()
      .toArray();
    res.json(files);
  });
});
```

Problem was I failed to check if munk connection manager returned proper db instance.

Comment: Can you confirm that in fact calling `files.find()` does what it's supposed to? Do you get an error or does `result` actually resolve with some data?

Comment: goto1, in fact files.find() is the same as db.get('fs.files').find() which should be the same mongodb collection method find() if we believe monk documentation. It takes all args as supposed, returns pending promise if called as synchronous function.

Comment: @goto1, and I get no error, all 3 endpoints just timeout.

Comment: What if you call `then` on that pending promise if you’re calling it outside of the middleware function? Does it resolve with what you’re expecting?

Comment: Also, `then` only takes a single callback, in your second example, you’re passing a callback handler and an error handler, but that’s not how you handle errors with promises. Promise errors are handled in the `catch` handler.

Comment: I've checked log of docker which runs mongod. Looks like I've got problems with authentication. Shall revert once get sorted. @goto1

Answer (score 0):

Solution : **Change db.get('fs.files'); to db.get('files');**

This is my demo project ->
database  : demo,
collections : users

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require('monk')('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo');
const files = db.get('users');

app.get('/1', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await files.find();
  res.json(result);
});

app.get('/2', (req, res) => {
  files.find()
   .then(
      (result) => { res.json(result) },
      (error) => { res.json(error) }
   );
});

app.get('/3', (req, res) => {
  files.find({}, (result) => {
    res.json(result)
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening at 4000')
  })
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Thanks, Debasis. 'fs.files' as well as 'fs.chunks' are special collections created by GridFS. I need to query this particular collection.

Comment: change  const files = db.get('fs.files')  to   const files = db.collection('fs.files');
and try it. let me know your update.

Comment: Looks like problem with authentication, please check comment above.